# Die probability and net gain, expected result

Tags: probability

The question is:

> Suppose you roll a fair 6-sided die. If you roll a 2 you win $\$4$, and
>   if you roll a 3 you win $\$6$. If you roll any other number, you win
>   nothing. You must pay $1 to roll the die once. What is your expected
>   net gain (in dollars) for a single roll?

and the solution is as follows:

> Let X be a random variable representing your gain from a single roll.
>
> If you roll a 2, $X = 3$.
>
> If you roll a 3, $X = 5$.
>
> If you roll a $1, 4, 5,$ or $6$, $X = −1$.
>
> It’s a fair die, so $P(X = 1) = 1/6, P(X = 2) = 1/6 , P(X
>   = −1) = 4/6$.
>
> $E(X) = 3·P(X =1) + 5·P(X =2) − 1·P(X =−1) = 2/3$

What I am not understanding is where $P(X = 1)$ and $P(X = 2)$ came from or what they are.

Comment: "fair" here means that the probability of throwing any value among $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is equal (hence $\frac 16$).

Comment: Looks like a mere typo, thankfully. (so it should be $P(X=3) = 1/6$ in the line about fair dice and $3\cdot P(X=3)$ et al in the final expectation calculation.

Comment: @DanUznanski Oh okay it makes sense now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Where did you copy this from? There is a typo, the author should have either been consistently using the variable $X$ as he defines it, and express everything with it, or introduce another variable for the roll of the dice. He or she somehow mixed the two.

What should have been written is $P(X=3)=1/6$, $P(X=5)=1/6$ and $P(X=-1)=2/3$, so $E(X)= 3\cdot P(X=3)+5\cdot P(X=5)+(-1)\cdot P(X=-1) = 2/3$.